# What happened to TicketMonster?

Tags: jboss-developer-studio

https://developers.redhat.com/ticket-monster/ links to a live demo at http://ticketmonster-jdf.rhcloud.com/, but it appears to be down or have been removed. Is there another live example of this demo app somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was deployed on OpenShift v2 Online which as been decomissioned. We are working on the migration to OpenShift v3

Comment: Did the migration complete?